# Unhandled Exception?

Tags: java

I've spent hours trying to figure this out; I'm new to Java and I can't seem to find out why the java Thread function is throwing an exception error. Can anyone explain this to me.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Loops {

    public static void main(String [] args) {



        Date today = new Date();
        System.out.println(today);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2015, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0);

        while (today.before(cal.getTime()))
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            today = new Date();
            System.out.println(today);
        }

        System.out.println("Done");


    }

}
```

Comment: What have you spent your hours doing to try and fix it?

Comment: I can't read your thoughts. Be a little bit more specific please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `Thread.java` API, the method `sleep();`, throws exception.

```
public static native void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException;
```

So it is required to `catch the exception` or `re-throw the exception`.

**Throw Exception**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Date today = new Date();
        System.out.println(today);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2015, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0);

        while (today.before(cal.getTime())) {
            System.out.println("Waiting");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            today = new Date();
            System.out.println(today);
        }

        System.out.println("Done");

    }
```

**Catch Exception**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date today = new Date();
        System.out.println(today);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2015, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0);

        while (today.before(cal.getTime())) {
            System.out.println("Waiting");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            today = new Date();
            System.out.println(today);
        }

        System.out.println("Done");

    }
```

Comment: @ ankur-singhal, Thank You; after studying up on try catch I understand a little better.